# Let X be the number showing on a fair six-sided die. What bound does Chebychev’s inequality give for $P(X ≥ 5 \text{ or } X ≤ 2)$?

Tags: probability

Let X be the number showing on a fair six-sided die. What bound does Chebychev’s
inequality give for $P(X ≥ 5 \text{ or }  X ≤ 2)$?

$E(X) = \frac{1}{6}(1+2+3+4+5+6) = 3.5$

$Var(X) = ?$

$P(X \geq 5 \text{ or } X \leq 2) = P(|X - E(X)| \geq a)$

Could someone explain how to do this question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$. And

$$E(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2\cdot P(X=i)=\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^6 i^2$$

Then it should be obvious that $X \geq 5 \text{ or } X \leq 2$ is equal to $|X-3.5|\geq 1.5$. To see that just solve the latter inequality.

Then we have  Chebyshev´s inequality

$$P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

That means $k\sigma=1.5 \quad (*)$

When you have evaluated $Var(X)$ you can take the square root to obtain $\sigma$. And finally you calculate the value of $k$ by using the equation $(*)$.